# Haxe: define a function/macro which fires when an object goes out of scope?

Tags: macros, scope, metaprogramming, haxe

Is this possible in Haxe to have the compiler automatically insert a function call / code segment at the point where an object instance goes out of scope? I have object instances that require manual cleanup beyond what garbage collection does (for the JS target).

**More Info**

I'm experimenting with allocating small data structures in JavaScript code manually inside a virtual heap (an `ArrayBuffer`), similar to what is done with compiled asm.js programs. I am using Haxe in part because I can create abstract types as convenient aliases/abstractions for their underlying data allocated in the heap (always some manner of `ArrayBufferView`), while suffering no runtime overhead from the abstraction.

The only issue is that deallocation must be done manually. It's simple enough to resort to calling a destructor function manually within code, but I find this error-prone and messy. I was hoping Haxe would have some mechanism I could use to automate the insertion of these function calls whenever a variable went out of scope, in a deterministic, compile-time manner.

Comment: It seems that this is not easy to achieve in haxe, partly due to the fact that GC depends heavily upon the target language / platform. It may also destruct objects at rather unpredictable times (not immediately after they go OOS), which could lead to bugs or complications. Maybe you could try alternative solutions? Mind providing some additional info on your specific project?

Comment: @Aurel300 I have added some more info in an edit.

Comment: I see. Once again, there seem to be no destructors in haxe… How about a `with` / `using` kind of macro? As in `using(/* parameters for your struct */, function(a:YourStruct){ /* do things with it */ });` – this would then expand / be inlined to the initialisation of the struct, the core function, then the destructor functions … Or is this too much overhead / not usable?