# Is it possible to automatically execute code when a local variable goes out of scope in Haxe?

Tags: scope, metaprogramming, haxe

I am looking for a way to automatically run some code when a local variable goes out of function scope with Haxe 3.2.1.

When I `get()` an object from a pool I sometimes want to guarantee that it is `put()` back when the original `get()`-ed variable goes out of scope. More generally I mean a behavior like [scoped_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm) in C++. I figure a macro might work, so that:

```
function makeWidget():Widget {
   return new Widget(PointPool.getScoped());
}
```

Gets transformed into:

```
function makeWidget():Widget {
   var __a = PointPool.get();
   var __b = new Widget(__a);
   __a.put();
   return __b;
}
```

But this gets over my head with `return switch...`, multiple `return`s and so on. So I am wondering, are there some other approaches to solving this problem with Haxe?

EDIT: I noticed a similar problem has been asked about before: [Haxe: define a function/macro which fires when an object goes out of scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572190/haxe-define-a-function-macro-which-fires-when-an-object-goes-out-of-scope) - it seems like a macro that inserts `get()` and `put()/destroy()` calls in the proper places would be a good approach - I'll answer if I work this one out.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Curious.

If you're targeting cpp, you could possibly use `scoped_ptr` directly, although I don't have any real-world experience with that, not sure how feasible that would be.

Comment: @FullOfCaffeine For scope-bound resource management, or a bit like "finally" in Java. Also just found it now, but this haxelib looks like my answer: http://lib.haxe.org/p/scopes

Comment: That haxelib looks like the right approach.  If it works for you, you should post the answer to your own question :)  If not, you could look at their code and change it as you see fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of feature was discussed before on the Haxe issue tracker: https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/3335

Jacek Szymański implemented this haxelib for scope guards: https://bitbucket.org/parensoft/scopes - and it solves the problem.

The generated code is a tangle because of exception handling and name mangling, but that's unavoidable from what I can see.